# Angular : load lots of data via directive causing browser issue

Tags: angularjs, amcharts

I have an angular directive loading a svg map (using amchart) where I add thousands of svg circles. In the end everything works but my browser seems in pain and I would need to (1) optimize my loading and (2) display a loading symbol that could last till the map can actually display for real.
Today I use this kind of directive attribute to know when my directive is loaded :

```
        directive('initialisation',['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {
              return {
                   restrict: 'A',
                   link: function($scope) {
                    var to;
                    var listener = $scope.$watch(function() {
                       clearTimeout(to);
                       to = setTimeout(function () {
                          listener();
                          $rootScope.$broadcast('initialised');
                       }, 50);
                   });
               }
            };
```

Well this is not good to me as my loading symbol (angular-material) freezes, and then disappear to leaves an empty browser for a few seconds, before the map can render. For information I use ng-hide on the loading div and ng-show on the map div, and this is the way I apply it :

```
$scope.$on('initialised', function() {

         $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.mapLoaded = true;
         });
    })
```

Do you know a way to solve my (1) and (2) issue ? Or should I look for another js library to do this?

Thank you

PS : here is my map directive (images is an array with 20k entry at the moment) :

```
 directive('amChartsLanguage', function() {
          return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace:true,
            template: '<div id="mapLanguage" style="height: 1000px; margin: 0 auto"> </div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


                var chart = false;

                var initChart = function() {
                    if (chart) chart.destroy();
                    var images = [];
                    var legendData = [];
                    for(var i=0 ; i < scope.languageZeppelin.length ; i ++ ) {
                        images.push( {
                            "type": "circle",
                            "width": 7,
                            "height": 7,
                            "color": scope.languageZeppelin[i].color,
                            "longitude": scope.languageZeppelin[i].lon,
                            "latitude": scope.languageZeppelin[i].lat
                          } );

                    }

                    var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                    legend.width="10%";
                    legend.height="300";
                    legend.equalWidths = false;
                    legend.backgroundAlpha = 0.5;
                    legend.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
                    legend.borderColor = "#ffffff";
                    legend.borderAlpha = 1;
                    legend.verticalGap = 10;
                    legend.top = 150;
                    legend.left = 70;
                    legend.position = "left";
                    legend.maxColumns = 1;
                    legend.data = scope.legend; 

                    // build map
                    chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "mapLanguage", {
                      "type": "map",
                      "areasSettings": {
                        "unlistedAreasColor": "#15A892",
                        "autoZoom": true,
                        "selectedColor": "#FFCC00",
                        "color": "#909090"
                      },
                      "dataProvider": {
                        "map": "worldLow",
                        "getAreasFromMap": true,
                        "images": images,
                        "zoomLevel": 1,
                        "zoomLongitude": 6,
                        "zoomLatitude": 11
                      },
                      "export": {
                        "enabled": false
                      }
                    } );

                    chart.addLegend(legend);

                    chart.validateNow(legend);


                };
                initChart();

            }
        }
        })
```

Comment: 1) angular is hardly the root cause of your problems. probably it is a combination of misusing the angular and having lots of data to load into the chart. You can do many thing in angular that will "work", but not in the way how it was intended to be used. Still, your delay most probably comes from amCharts. Have you tried to use time profiling from Chrome?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will have a look at chrome and let you know. As you imagined, I have not much experience with angular, but I am sure drawing a few thousands svg in a browser shouldnt take 5s. Do you know any other js librairy that could do the trick ?

Comment: By the way, how am I misusing angular here ?

Comment: For one, you have put too much functionality to the link method, hence your DOM compilation takes as long as populating the chart. How it could be done better, is that you add all the DOM elements, and then update it with data in controller. link methods should be as lean as possible.

Comment: 20k data points is quite a bit outside of what the AmCharts maps library can comfortably handle all at once, performance-wise and, from a user experience perspective, likely not easy to read. You might want to consider alternative techniques to manage that, such as implementing a [marker drill-down](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/map-marker-drill-down/) or [showing markers a specific zoom levels](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/show-groups-map-images-specific-zoom-level/) rather than showing them all at once to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

we have angular with a lot more data on the page. with poor design og architechture. loading ofcoarse too long but after that performance is great. we use d3